# Center and fill image in Ionic Columns

Tags: html, css, ionic4

I am going to add products images to an IONIC web application in the Ionic grid with following HTML
I have managed to center

text in the columns, but when adding images in place of

text, height of grid columns changes and images also does not fit properly.

```
<ion-header>
   <ion-toolbar>
      <ion-title>  
         Grid Example  
      </ion-title>
   </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>
<ion-content class="padding" color="light">
   <ion-grid >
      <ion-row class="parent-row">
         <ion-col size="7" class="col1">
            <p class="center-image">Image1</p>
         </ion-col>
         <ion-col class="col2">
            <ion-row class="image2">
               <p class="center-image">Image2</p>
            </ion-row>
            <ion-row class="image3">
               <p class="center-image">Image3</p>
            </ion-row>
         </ion-col>
      </ion-row >
   </ion-grid>
</ion-content>
```

and following css.

```
.parent-row {
    height: 300px;
}

.col1 {
    background-color: red;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    overflow: hidden
}

.col1 img {
    flex-shrink: 0;
    max-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
}

.col2 {
    background-color: orange;
}

.image2 {
    background-color: yellow;
    height: 50%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    overflow: hidden
}

.image2 img {
    flex-shrink: 0;
    min-width: auto;
    min-height: auto;
}

.image3 {
    background-color: green;
    height: 50%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    overflow: hidden
}

.image3 img {
    flex-shrink: 0;
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: auto;
}

.center-image {}
```

I get following result

[image]
When I replace

with image, images crosses the given height of column i.e. 300px
I want my products images to fit in columns in place of Image 1 , 2 & 3, without changing the dimensions of columns.

Comment: I think you need to play with background-size values. I think either cover or contain should work fine for you https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/playit.asp?filename=playcss_background-size&preval=cover